# setting image dynamically from database by its name

Tags: android, database, image, xml-drawable

I am getting the name of the image from database eg *R.drawable.abc* in a string Arraylist
For this I used the following code to set the image in the list view:

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("com.mypackage:drawable/" + arr_img.get(position),
                        null, null);
imageview.setImageResource(id);
```

here arr_img is the ArrayList type in which i have all the names.
But the images cannot be seen.. please help thanks.

-----CODE--------

```
private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private ArrayList<String> myAdptr;

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,

    ArrayList<String> sList) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, sList);
        this.myAdptr = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.myAdptr.addAll(stg1);
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView code;
        CheckBox name;
        ImageView imageview;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.new_search_adptr, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.code = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.adapterText1);
            holder.name = (CheckBox) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

            holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

            holder.name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;

                    if (cb.isChecked()) {

                        // User checked (selected) a car
                        // *********************************


                        if (cntr > 1) {

                            // More than two cars selected

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Please select only two cars!",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            cb.setChecked(false);

                        } else {

                            // car selected

                            if (cntr == 0) {
                                c1_make = arr_make.get(position);
                                c1_model = arr_model.get(position);
                                c1_ver = arr_ver.get(position);
                            }

                            if (cntr == 1) {
                                c2_make = arr_make.get(position);
                                c2_model = arr_model.get(position);
                                c2_ver = arr_ver.get(position);
                            }

                            cntr++;

                        }

                    } else {

                        // User Unchecked (de - selected) a car
                        // *********************************


                        cntr--;

                        if (cntr == 0) {
                            c1_make = null;
                            c1_model = null;
                            c1_ver = null;
                        }

                        if (cntr == 1) {
                            c2_make = null;
                            c2_model = null;
                            c2_ver = null;
                        }

                    }



                }
            });

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        String state = myAdptr.get(position);

        holder.code.setText(stg1.get(position).toString());


        for (int m = 0; m < arr_img.size(); m++) {

            System.out.println(m+" --- "+arr_img.get(m));
        }

        int id = getResources()
                .getIdentifier(
                        "com.carlist:drawable/" + arr_img.get(position),
                        null, null);
        holder.imageview.setImageResource(id);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you stored your image in arraylist?

Comment: no the image is in drawable folder.. its name is in arraylist

Comment: please post your code where you have implemented this:

Comment: the image name which you have stored in arraylist if its contains .png or .jpg extension?

Comment: no it does not have any extension

Comment: can you post your xml file and code where you have stored imahes?

Answer (score 0):

Just change it with may be this will help you.

```
 for (int m = 0; m < arr_img.size(); m++) {

         int id = getResources()
            .getIdentifier(
                    "com.carlist:drawable/" + arr_img.get(m),
                    null, null);
    holder.imageview.setImageResource(id);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

when you got the file name of your image then you can use one of following code section to set the image into image view.

```
String imageName = "picture"
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", "package.name");
ImageView image;
imageview.setImageResource(resID );
```

or you can also try the following code

```
String imageId = "imageId"
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(imageString , "id", "package.name");
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(resID);
```